# Create "Provider" in Java with Oauth library?

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-provider

I downloaded the examples (https://code.google.com/p/oauth/) compiled and loaded the provider and consumer WAR files to Apache Tomcat.

I configured **provider.properties with:**
Consumer_key=mysecret   (i'm not sure if i can set this as key)
Consumer_key.description=Get a GPS position
Consumer_key.callbackURL=http://localhost:8081/oauthC/OAuth/Callback

**consumer.properties with:**
sample.serviceProvider.baseURL: http://localhost:8081/oauthP/
sample.serviceProvider.requestTokenURL: request_token
sample.serviceProvider.userAuthorizationURL: authorize
sample.serviceProvider.accessTokenURL: access_token
sample.consumerKey: mysecret
sample.consumerSecret: mysecret  (i'm quite confused what should i set in this attr)

and start the server. I accessed http://localhost:8081/oauthC/ (consumer site) go to sample and it returned this:

OAuthProblemException:
**oauth_problem:    token_rejected**

**HTTP request:** GET /oauthP/request_token?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2FoauthC%2FOAuth%2FCallback%3Fconsumer%3Dsample%26returnTo%3D%252FoauthC%252FSampleProvider&oauth_consumer_key=mysecret&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1298329818&oauth_nonce=13474056411695&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=JwuEr0jprO8G3bKRhXHdqpeuuxI%3D
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: localhost:8081

**HTTP status:      401**

**HTTP response:** HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost.localdomain", oauth_problem="token_rejected"
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 28
Date: Mon, 21 Feb 2011 23:10:18 GMT
oauth_problem=token_rejected

**oauth_signature base string:** GET&http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2FoauthP%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8081%252FoauthC%252FOAuth%252FCallback%253Fconsumer%253Dsample%2526returnTo%253D%25252FoauthC%25252FSampleProvider%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dmysecret%26oauth_nonce%3D13474056411695%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1298329818%26oauth_version%3D1.0

**URL:** http://localhost:8081/oauthP/request_token?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2FoauthC%2FOAuth%2FCallback%3Fconsumer%3Dsample%26returnTo%3D%252FoauthC%252FSampleProvider&oauth_consumer_key=mysecret&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1298329818&oauth_nonce=13474056411695&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=JwuEr0jprO8G3bKRhXHdqpeuuxI%3D

I'm stuck at this. Anyone can give an advice ? or show me documentation for this lib ? i can't find anything...

thx for ur time